# Is Windows Universal App for me? - UI Migration

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a console app that does some Database management stuff connecting directly to them. It works for MsSqlServer and Oracle (for now).

As you might know, using a console app is not so productive. So I wanted to port the UI part to a Desktop app. I have all core code in a library, console app just manages user interaction.

I did some testing and can't use libraries on UWA. Then tried shared libraries and to my surprise I can't use SqlServer directly.

Are UWA the new way to do desktop apps? I dont want to connect to services and then to the database, it's good for user apps, but dont feel confident for the stuff my software does, i need 100% direct connection.

Should I try with WPF (does it work with sqlserver connections?)? WinForms? What if they drop support for WPF or WinForms like they going to do with WebForms?

Wanted UWA because it looks very good and MS made it look like it's 'the way to go'.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

So, some people say I could use web api or middle tier that can handle all the tasks and this way i can get around the restrictiveness of UWA.
It's not a bad idea, i also thought about this. Even thought i can just have a service for tasks, and web UI, that way it will be accesible from any device. BUT harder to deploy in private/corporate nerworks.

I think it's too much architecture just for a "simple" tool.

So, after some thinkning found (probably) some middle level answer to this: I will research what projects can help me to do a native integration with Windows and other systems. Since Phones and Tablets are probably out of my targets already, then at least I will target linux and mac os .

Think this new .Net version they are working on it's going to be OSS and also multiplatform. Going to check it out and keep this post updated in case anyone else is interested.

**UPDATE 2**

Now im really thinking on the middle tier, but it gonna make it more complicated and longer to develop :(

For this i will need: my core library, a windows service or some kind of job/task service, front end probably html5 consuming some webapi.

Any recommendations on the task/job server?

Comment: *"Are UWA the new way to do desktop apps?"* No. They are the new way to do "write once, run on any Windows device" apps. Quite new, in fact; that wasn't possible before. But they certainly do not replace desktop applications. Will you ever want to run this database management app on a phone or a tablet? If not, there seems little point in targeting UWA.

Comment: I'm a windows phone user, so yes, it was on my view to to this.  But not a priority you know? This software mainly deploys scripts, but also retrieves some DB health stats and info , which i wanted to have on my phone or tablet. What do you think? shoul I go for winforms?
I thiknk i will drop the idea of phone and tablet support, i think it is too early for IT apps to use UWA.

Comment: They may be a good way to start an app... but the future of application development, in my opinion, is WebApps with a MVVM front-end (Aurelia, Angular 2)

Comment: It gets more complicated since it requires jobs and tasks. Then I will need some kind of really heavy backend just for couple of users?
I love the idea of webapps (i have a few of them  running) but i dont see them fit on my requirements.
Thanks for your reply anyways!

Comment: From my perspective plain old fashioned Windows Form app would be the easiest with the most mature toolset available, and no, I don't see microsoft dropping support for Windows Form Applications anytime in the foreseeable future. If you want to just see the data on the phone a very simple approach would just be to have the app publish the data you need to a basic web server as HTML. Easy to do and you could grab the latest data from any platform that can look at a web page.

Comment: Regarding Update 2 - Keep it simple, make a console app that just does the work you want done and use Task Scheduler in windows to kick it off at whatever schedule needs to happen. With a few tricks you can even make an app that is either a windows form app or a console app depending on the command line settings. You could write the code to work in simple processing mode or give you a useful UI.
Based on your description I am assuming this isn't something that needs to be monitoring this real time, if so then look further into a windows service.

Comment: @drobertson I really appreciate your words mate, thanks.!

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, they don't support a lot of the System.Data functionality in the UWA application and you can't use handy tools like DataTable's or DataReaders (even the Sqlite implementation for UWA's doesn't have a DataReader which makes getting dynamic data difficult where you don't know the model in advance).

The recommended approach is to have a middle tier of any sort that you can call that does all of the data access for you (that approach is fine but isn't going to work for everyone's environment).

I see your options as:

1. Create the UWA app with a middle tier somewhere that does the data access calls and exposes an API in whatever flavor you decide that should be.
2. If you want XAML in the UI but UWA is too restrictive, create a WPF app where you have the full framework at your disposal to do what you want as you want.  This means you can likely use all of the .Net libraries you've previously used (like your SqlServer and Oracle ADO.Net providers).
3. Use WinForms, still works, less friendly for high DPI apps (but not impossible).  WinForms are "mature" as per Microsoft.  They don't get a lot of new features but they're not going anywhere soon.  You also have the full framework available without the UWA restrictions as with WPF.

Comment: 1) Yes, i was thinking exactly that, but where that middle tier going to be sitting? Cant be local, got to be a service located elsewhere (can be local , but you know what i mean).
2) Probably going to go this way. 
3) Totally understand.

Comment: You're asking the right questions.  If you don't have to distribute through the Windows Store then it sounds to me like WPF/WinForms become attractive for you.  If it's a utility for yourself you don't necessarily need the overhead of that middle tier (my example would be which seems similar to the case you posed, does SQL Server Management Studio limit itself to the UWA API's and use a middle tier?  The answer is no, it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can develop a simple API and then you can use an UWP.
With this API you can get the stats data and also make calls for script deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, read my comments about this ideas.

Thanks

Comment: @JuanCarlos I wanted to say the same that b.pell. Use WPF for all heavy work and use UWP to display the data with an API, you can put your API in the same machine (or in other) where your DB is located, and then use JSON to send the data to your UWP.

Comment: Of course, this solution also ocurred to me, but dont you think it's just too much complicated?
Just needed to have some sexy buttons and lists. Prob WPF will do, but I just dont want to change platforms once MS move away from it and aim 100% to UWA.

Was checking QT, but not free to use for commercial software.

Comment: I think MS never will go to 100% UWP, because UWP doesn't use the full .Net framework, so you couldn't have low level access in desktop apps. UWP for example doesn't allow create a datagram or read from system buffers.

Comment: That's True. If i tell you the truth I was really disappointed when all these stuff failed. Cos then its not 100% universal. If i'm going to make an app with midtier backend then i would preffer to do it in some web solution like cordova or something similar, even just a webapp would be better (and faster) development of a software of this capabilities.

Why use UWA when html can do the same?

**Updating my main post**

Comment: If you know C# and XAML I think that it's easiest develop an UWP than a cordova or Ionic webapp. However if you want to support Windows, Linux, Mac Os, iOS, Android ... In my opinion I would develop a website with two pages, 1 for authentication and the other to show the data

Comment: Problem is not to develop the web frontend, but the service to run the tasks. On web is good practice not to do multitheading or blocking operations, so to "fix" this issue the site would use a  task/job service which the site will poll to see the status of such tasks. Its easy and I have done it before. But this complicates TOO much. This wont be commercial software, its used mainly by my and some programmers and DBAs.


Imagine, IF a simple calculator app needs webapi to work, so everytime you going to install the calculator on a desktop you need first to deploy a backend with APIs.