# Configuration for C# Class Library being used in multiple environments

Tags: .net, configuration

I am building a class library in C# .NET Framework 4.6 that is consolidating and simplifying the data access to a wide variety of  back end data sources. These data sources are Azure Tables, Azure Blobs, Redis Cache, DocumentDB data and external REST APIs. All of this data is being used by multiple systems on different platforms. At this point we have a huge mess of disparate systems that all need to be maintained separately every time one of the back end data sources changes even slightly. Changing a table means we need to update code in between 5 to 7 codebases.

The problem is that this class library is going to be used from ASP.NET 2 & 4, ASP.NET Core 1.0 and Windows Forms applications. There is a possibility that it could also be used in other environments.

The challenge is that each location will need a way to set their own config strings and access keys. I would like this to just be a section of the config file where you add your info. The library would read the keys and be ready to go, just the way many libraries do.

My problem is that there seems to be no common way of accessing settings on these platforms. I would prefer to not create a custom settings accessor for every platform this could be used on.

Could someone give me a straightforward solution that is easy to implement and maintain. Ideally it would not require much in the way of outside dependencies.

As a side question, are there any other gotchas I should expect dealing with these different systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a class that needs a connection string, put the connection string in the class's constructor. The class shouldn't get the string directly from web.config or anywhere else.

Like this:

```
public class ReadsSomethingFromSql
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public ReadsSomethingFromSql(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public void InsertSomethingIntoSql()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            //Do something with connection string
        }
    }
}
```

That way the class isn't responsible for reading from web.config. That could be really confusing because someone using the class might now know that the class is expecting a connections string to be in web.config. By putting it in the constructor it's clear that the class needs a connection string.

If you're not using dependency injection then your calling method could do this:

```
var reader = new ReadsSomethingFromSql(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString);
```

But that could just move the problem. If you're creating that class instance *from within your own library* then you've still got the same problem - your library is reading directly from web.config.

A better solution is to use dependency injection to specify all of the values that your class depends on. (It's a big subject to expand on in this post. Here's a [starting example](http://roland.kierkels.net/c-asp-net/dependency-injection-using-castle-windsor/) of dependency injection using Castle Windsor.)

Using that, you could specify where the connection string comes from like this:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<ReadsSomethingFromSql>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connectionString",
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString))
    );
```

If it's more than just a connection string, maybe a number of settings that your class needs, then you can create an interface, like this:

```
public interface ISettings
{
    string Setting1 { get; }
    int SomeOtherSetting { get; }
}
```

and put that in the constructor of your class just like the connection string above.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ISettings settings;

    public MyClass(ISettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
```

That way your class refers to `_settings` which is an instance of `ISettings` but it doesn't "know" what the implementation is.

Then you can create a class that implements `ISettings` that gets values from configuration, like this:

```
public class Settings : ISettings
{
    public string Setting1 { get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyClass:Setting1"]; } }
    public int SomeOtherSetting {
        get
        {
            return Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyClass:SomeOtherSettings"]);
        }
    } }
}
```

That will solve your problem of your class depending on configuration. It won't depend on configuration. It will depend on `ISettings`.

Using Windsor your appliciation would configure it like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISettings,Settings>());
```

I'm not really doing dependency injection justice with these cursory examples. But I started down the exact same path with the exact same questions. Dependency injection is the answer, and will benefit you in a lot of other ways as well.

**Update:**
You mentioned that you don't want to have to modify consumers of the class. I think I see part of the problem - your Core 1.0 apps won't have a web.config.

You could compromise. Modify the constructor for your class and make the arguments optional. That way when you're writing new consumers you can use dependency injection. The old consumers can just work like they do now, like this:

```
public class ReadsSomethingFromSql
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public ReadsSomethingFromSql(string connectionString = null)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString
            ?? ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, this gives me a good direction to investigate. I really want to get this right and get it off my plate. If I do it wrong I can see a long future of supporting this in ways I don't want. I really don't want to have to rewrite it for every new consumer of the library.

Comment: I have been working on the dual approach you mentioned above. I am refactoring the system to work on Dependency Injection. This seems to fit in very well with the ASP.NET core model that will be one of the main consumers of the library. Internally I am also giving the library the ability to fallback to standard config files.
At this point it feels a bit messy, but I am sure that after a refactor or two I will have it sorted. Internally the DI model and the config file model resolve to the same objects on the inside. It could almost be considered internal DI.
Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Im not completely sure of what you want:

1) Library config data needs to be located in the config file of the main project?
2) Library need to have ALL other projects' config data embedded in its own config?

If #1 if what you neeed, then its just as easy as using your configuration file. I have currently in production, 4 webapps that use 4 libraries, 2 of them have custom config on the project that is using it. I use appSettings webconfig section. And library WILL read that config file using:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["<CONFIG KEY HERE>"]
```

If #2, then its more or less the same. Just write custom config for library with everything there and then just release it with all data with it. But i would preffer doing number 1.

If i just got your question wrong, then sorry! If you explain it more detailed what is your scenario like, then I'll be happy to help you.

> As a side question, are there any other gotchas I should expect
>   dealing with these different systems.

This is BAD BAD BAD! I'm just having a related issue. Check my post: [Is Windows Universal App for me? - UI Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816139/is-windows-universal-app-for-me-ui-migration)

Having framework 2 and 4 is going to bring you problems, also mixing platforms and SPECIALLY recent microsoft technologies, like aspnet core and UWA.

I would check TWICE and do some extensive testing before spending anytime coding something that just not going to work.

Cheers

Comment: I think you have it close. Each project using this library would have its own config and that config would contain the settings and connection strings for the library (at least that is the goal). Thanks for the link to your experience, that is frightening and helpful.

Comment: The problem with your recomendation is what led me to ask the question. ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["<CONFIG KEY HERE>"] doesn't actually work the same in each envirionment and it specificly fails in ASP.NET core 1, which I regretably need to deal with.

Comment: You can try to do preprocessor programming and "choose"  where the library is going, so depending on that compile target you change where you taking the data from. I would do this if all these targets are going to be what they are now (ie all over the place).

You going to share something with LOTS of different technologies, best you can do if do something "homemade" that you know how it works and how to change it in case some other new projects uses some other technology.